# Is this an efficient calculator in Python?

Tags: python, performance, calculator

Is this an efficient calculator in Python?

```
def calculator():

    print("\nBasic Calculator.\n")

    num_1 = input("Enter your first number: ")
    operation = input("Enter your operation: ")
    num_2 = input("Enter your second number: ")

    if operation == ("+"):
        sum = float(num_1) + float(num_2)
        print ("The answer is:",(sum))

    elif operation == ("-"):
        sum = float(num_1) - float(num_2)
        print ("The answer is:",(sum))

    elif operation == ("*"):
        sum = float(num_1) * float(num_2)
        print ("The answer is:",(sum))

    elif operation == ("/") and num_2 == ("0"):
        print ("\nYou cannot divide by zero.")

    elif operation == ("/"):
        sum = float(num_1) / float(num_2)
        print ("The answer is:",(sum))

    else:
        print("Invalid Operation.")

    restart = input("\nDo you want to enter another equation? Yes or No?").lower()

    if restart == ("yes"):
        calculator()

    else:
        print ("\nEnding Program.")
        quit()

calculator()
```

Comment: It's decent, but reviews of working code belong on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Comment: Call the result `result` instead of `sum`, that obviously only is meaningful for addition.

Comment: Oh sorry, i've only just found the website so i'm still figuring it all out

Comment: k3nny321: that's okay

Answer (score 3):

You can use `eval()`

```
a = 1
b = 2
operation = '/'
print(eval(f'{a} {operation} {b}'))
```

```
0.5
```

Handle shenanigans by users:

```
a = 1
b = 0
operation = '/'
try:
    print(eval(f'{a} {operation} {b}'))
except Exception as exp:
    print(exp)
```

Comment: I'll give this a go 

Comment: Catch the `ZeroDivisionError`

Comment: Use an `try` and `except` block to catch `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: Note that this only works with python 3.6 and above.

Comment: I believe I am using the latest edition with PyCharm CE

Answer (score 1):

It's decent, but reviews of working code belong on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not here.

- Call the result variable `result` instead of `sum`, that obviously only is meaningful for addition.
- As per AlexanderLekontsev's answer, you don't need a huge big `if...else` ladder that always computes `result` and prints the output. A dispatch dictionary to (binary or unary) lambda function is better. You could have all the functions be binary, and default `arg2=None`, that way you can handle unary functions.
- You're assuming the user types in valid floats in response to `num_1`, `num_2`. But what if they press return? or type `pi` or `e`? or 'help' or `:-D` etc. You should catch the exception `ValueError: could not convert string to float`and display the user's invalid input back to them, "expected a number"(/"operator").

  - You only need `num_2` if `operation` is a binary not a unary operation, but future stuff like `sqrt`, log, log10, trigonometrics (`sin, cos, tan`), hyperbolics and their inverses (arc-fns) are all unary operations. Just something to keep in mind for the future. Don't hardwire your parser to one expected input sequence.
  - Inputting numbers could get more complicated in future. What if you wanted to support both hexadecimal `7e8` and float/general/exponential notation `7e8`? You might need multiple `try...except` clauses. You might add a `HEX` mode in future. But then you'll need to generalize from `num1` to say `arg1`, and if `arg1` == `HEX` then enable(/toggle) hex mode, and recurse/loop.
- Suggest printing `print("Invalid Operation: must be +,-,*,/,...")`, this actually tells the user which operations are legal. So: `%` isn't, neither is `^`, neither is `log`, `cos`, `sqrt` etc.
- So if you implement the above, you can support things like `e^x`
- Supporting parentheses would require recursion.

Comment: Cheers for the advice, I'll implement some of these changes now 

Answer (score 1):

Here is another basic example:

```
operations = {
    '+': lambda x, y: x + y,
    '-': lambda x, y: x - y,
    '*': lambda x, y: x * y,
    '/': lambda x, y: x / y,
}

try:
    x, sign, y = input("Enter expression separated by whitespace(ex: 2 + 3): ").split()
    if sign == '0':
        break
    else:
        print(operations[sign](int(x), int(y)))
except (ValueError, KeyError, ZeroDivisionError):
    print("Something went wrong, check your input")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def calculate(num1, num2, operator):
    operator = operator.strip()
    if operator.strip() in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
        if operator == '/' and eval(num2) == 0:
            return None
    try:
        result = eval(f'float({num1.strip()}) {operator} float({num2.strip()})')
    except:
        return ""
    return result

num1 = '3'
num2 = '5'
operator =  '+'

result = calculate(num1, num2, operator)

if result == '':
    print('Wrong expression !')
elif result == None:
    print('Dive bye zero !')
else:
    print(f'The answe is {result} !')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is alright but we can improvise by using eval()

```
print(" Basic Calculator ")
i = ""
while i != 'exit':
    i = input(" Enter the expression to evaluate or type 'exit' to exit : ")
    print(eval(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very clean and short calculator script:

```
num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
op = (input("Enter an operation: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter another number: "))
if op == "*":   
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
elif op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == "^":
    print(num1 ** num2)
else:
    print("error, you did not enter a supported operation")
```

Also if you were wondering ** means ^ or to the power of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
this calculator will take several inputs, and you can choose to clear the values or to delete it before computing the result.

```
values_collector = [] #empty list for all values
multi = 1
total = 0
index = 0

print('''For addition press the +,
         For Subtraction press the -
         For division press the /
         For Multiplication press the *''')

entries = int(input('Enter the number of the values you want to compute: '))
signs = input('Enter the sign: ')


while index < entries:
    my_input = int(input('Enter your values: '))
    values_collector.append(my_input)
    index +=1
    
to_remove = input('Do you want to remove any values, enter Y for yes and N for no ').upper()

if to_remove == 'Y':
    values_re=[]
    x = 0
    no_to_remove = int(input('How many variables do you want to remove: '))
    while x < no_to_remove:
        my_removed = int(input('Enter your values: '))
        values_re.append(my_removed)
        x +=1
        
    for y in values_re:
        values_collector.remove(y) 
        

my_clear = input("Do you want to clear all the values press Y for yes and N for No  ").upper()

if my_clear == 'Y':
    values_collector.clear()
    print('There is no values to compute because its cleared')

elif my_clear == 'N':
    if signs == '+':
        for x in range(len(values_collector)):
            total +=values_collector[x] 

    elif signs == '-':
        for x in range(len(values_collector)):
            total -=values_collector[x] 

    elif signs == '*':
        for x in range(len(values_collector)):
            multi *=values_collector[x] 
            total = multi

    elif signs == '/':
        for x in range(len(values_collector)):
            multi /=values_collector[x] 
            total = multi


    print('The computation of all the values {} is {}'.format(values_collector, total))
    
    
    enter code here
```