# Python: Calculator functions:

Tags: python

Can someone tell me how I can add functions for each numerical input below,
I've got one for the first input, but not the second, and the operator input?
Hope this is clearly explained,

```
def calculator():
    while True:
        try:
            num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
            break
        except:
            print("Please try again: ")
    operator = input("")

    while True:
        try:
            num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
            break
        except:
            print("Please try again: ")

    if operator == '+':
        print(num1 + num2)
    elif operator == '-':
        print(num1 - num2)
    elif operator == '/':
        print(num1 / num2)
    elif operator == '*':
        print(num1 * num2)
    else:
        print("Please try again")


while True:
    calculator()
```

Comment: So what is the problem of your code?

Comment: Near-duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62381867/is-this-an-efficient-calculator-in-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added one more while for you,Added Getnum Function for getting i/p

```
def GetNum():
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input("Enter first number: "))
            break
        except:
            print("Please try again: ")
    return(num)

def calculator():
    num1 = GetNum()

    while True:
        operator = input("Enter the operator + - * / : ")
        if operator == "+" or operator == "-" or operator == "*" or operator == "/":
            break
        else:
            print("Please try again: ")
    num2 = GetNum()
    
    if operator == '+':
        print(num1 + num2)
    elif operator == '-':
        print(num1 - num2)
    elif operator == '/':
        print(num1 / num2)
    elif operator == '*':
        print(num1 * num2)
    else:
        print("Please try again")
while True:
    calculator()
```

Comment: Thanks that's great,  Is there any way I can split the numercal inputs into extra functions?

Comment: Hello thanks for the above, just have one question.  In calculator(): when you call the operator, you created a while True: and then if statement.  Could this have been done by creating another try/except?

Comment: no need of try except there as if else will handle this....

Comment: you can test but entering any abcd to the operator and check it, please mark the solved answer

Comment: Okay then could an if-else handle the first and second numerical inputs?.  i'm just trying to find out difference that's all.

Comment: there we are checking only for + - * /,so if-else works. but in the number you are converting it to int, if they enter sting it will detect by try except only. you can not add all number to if like IF Num == 1 or num==2 or num==3 .......num==X

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want to do.

Your current problem is that there's no variable to keep the result, so I added a `result` as return value and a `num1` outside of the function.

```
def calculator(num1 = None):
    # if there's no num1 then ask for it
    # but skip it if a num1 already exists 
    while num1 == None: 
        try:
            num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
            break
        except:
            print("Not a valid number, please try again.")
    while True:
        operator = input("Enter the operator + - * / : ")
        if operator in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
            break
        else:
            print("Not a valid operator, please try again.")
    while True:
        try:
            num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
            break
        except:
            print("Not a valid number, please try again.")
 
    # eval() parses the expression in it
    # a tricky way to do the calculation
    result = eval(str(num1) + operator + str(num2))

    # no need to do the if-else operator check 
    # as it's already been done in the second while loop
    print("The final result is ", result)
    return result 

num1 = None #initliate a variable
while True:
    num1 = calculator(num1)
```

(Strictly speaking, there are many other subtle problems, but for the sake of simplicity and your current level, I think it's better to ignore them for now.)

Comment: Thanks that's great.